# Take the qualifiers - postgresql

Tags: c, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I'm working on the postgresql 8.4 source code. I need to extrapolate the qualifiers (where part) from the query.

For example if the query is: `select name from student where age > 18`
I need to know "age" and "18".

I've already took the target list, and the range list in this way

```
Query *query_idr = (Query *)linitial(querytree_list);
ListCell *l;
ListCell *tl;
foreach(l, query_idr->rtable){
        Oid tab_idT = ((RangeTblEntry *) lfirst(l)) ->relid;
}
foreach(tl, query_idr->targetList){
        TargetEntry *tle = (TargetEntry *) lfirst(tl);
        Oid col_id = tle->resorigtbl;
}
```

and it works, and I've got the id of the table `student` (with the first foreach) and id of `name` column (with the second foreach), but I can't understand how I have to take the qualifier.

Here is the navigable Query structure http://doxygen.postgresql.org/structQuery.html

Comment: Since people familiar with precisely that might be rare, I suggest adding links to relevant parts of public sources or docs, like docs and/or source declaration of those `Query` and `ListCell` structs. Also maybe show how you do get those `name` and `student`.

Comment: Actually, there is a mailing list for postgresql hackers: http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/ While I do appreciate your sense of SO community, I guess there'll be more knowledgeable  people there.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you are going to get an answer here.  In general hacking the PostgreSQL source code is not likely to have enough people here who can answer it that a general site like this will be helpful.  However rather than leave this withough any such resources I would like to reply to provide a list of resources for answering questions like this one as well as my reading of the docs as someone with quite a bit of experience buildign things on Pg.

In essence what you are trying to do is navigate through the parse tree of the query.  It looks to me like the setOperations member might be the place to look just because I can't think of anywhere else and because this might help with both join conditions and where clause filters (remember these are considered interchangeable by the planner).  However I have little experience in this area and so I could be wrong.

I would entirely second the suggestion that the pgsql-hackers list is likely to be the best place to ask this sort of question.  You will probably get a better answer there.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to analyze setOperations and in case write in pgsql-hackers.